# Chrome browser update affects CSS for link button icons

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, leaflet, display

I updated my Chrome browser from version 61 to 62, which caused the 2 button icons in my page's leaflet-sidebar to appear cut off, as if they've been shifted down. After some digging, I discovered that the buttons can be fixed by overwriting the following related code:

```css
.sidebar-tabs>ul>li>a {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sidebar-v2@0.3.1/css/leaflet-sidebar.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="sidebar-tabs">
  <ul role="tablist">
    <li id="myItemsButton"><a href="#myItems" class="sidebar-icon" role="tab"><i class="fa fa-list-ul"></i></a></li>
    <li id="mySettingsButton"><a href="#mySettings" class="sidebar-icon" role="tab"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

with this code:

```css
a.sidebar-icon {
    display: inline-block !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sidebar-v2@0.3.1/css/leaflet-sidebar.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="sidebar-tabs">
  <ul role="tablist">
    <li id="myItemsButton"><a href="#myItems" class="sidebar-icon" role="tab"><i class="fa fa-list-ul"></i></a></li>
    <li id="mySettingsButton"><a href="#mySettings" class="sidebar-icon" role="tab"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I'd like to know what changed in Chrome, or what was wrong with my original CSS/HTML, to cause this issue to suddenly appear. Does anyone have any insight?

**Edits:**

My code is using the latest [Leaflet-sidebar](https://github.com/Turbo87/sidebar-v2/releases/tag/v0.3.1) library. I found this issue by fiddling with the "display: block" fragment in Styles in the Chrome element inspector.

My specific Chrome browser is "Version 62.0.3202.62 (Official Build) (64-bit)" on Windows 7.

Comment: could you please make a fiddle? I don't know why nobody does that anymore

Comment: @user1435897 Why would a fiddle be necessary with embedded stack snippets?

Comment: I'm writing this on Chrome 61, and both examples looks ok when using Font Awesome on localhost. Are you sure, that you don't have any display scaling, browser zoom, font aliasing, or 3rd party plugin affecting this? Also - without the rest of the CSS (for the containers, sidebar, etc.) it's impossible to understand the problem that you are facing.

Comment: sorry I couldn't include my full code, so I tried to show just enough to explain the issue

Comment: because in a fiddle its possible to change the code its also more readable

Comment: @user1435897 you can easily copy the snippet to the answer with the click of a button, and edit it there in the same way as a fiddle. External links for code are discouraged on SO because they can change or be removed over time, so they are no longer useful to other users. The purpose of the snippet is to keep the code exactly as it is along side with the question/answer.

Comment: @FluffyKitten that was useful thanks

Comment: Its very difficult to help without seeing what's happening to the icons, which is why I included the fontawesome library. Even though you are using a different library, if it can be replicated with Font Awesome, I suggest adding them back so we can see the actual problem in action :)

Comment: @FluffyKitten oh my bad, didn't realize it removed those FA libraries when I edited my post at the same time

Comment: I also added the leaflet-sidebar library, and now when I run the code snippets I can reproduce the issue in my browser!

Comment: This appears to be an issue with Chrome.  The icons render for me fine in Firefox.

Comment: Correct, I tested multiple browser variants and only saw this in Chrome.